# Can't package and run electron app after signing and notarizing

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm having problems packaging my app, here's an outline of what's happening

1. If I don't code sign the app, I can package and run it fine
2. When I add my developer certificate to keychain and try to package the app, I get this error: `Could not automatically determine ElectronTeamID from identity.`

To fix this error I had this to my build configuration:

```
  "mac": {
    "extendInfo": {
      "ElectronTeamID": "xxx"
    },
  }
```

3. When I package and run the application I get this error: "The application cannot be opened." Looking at the logs I see `Code has restricted entitlements, but the validation of its code signature failed.`

To fix this I create a developer provisioning profile and add a reference to it in my build config

```
"mac": {
  "provisioningProfile": "provisioning_file",
}
```

4. when I package and runt he app again I get this error:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a2398f08

Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [45125]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1a2398f08 pthread_jit_write_protect_np + 516
1 Electron Framework 0x11abc49d8 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 38377608
2 Electron Framework 0x1179ade7c v8::internal::ThreadIsolation::Initialize(v8::ThreadIsolatedAllocator*) + 72
3 Electron Framework 0x117bc6328 v8::internal::V8::InitializePlatformForTesting(v8::Platform*) + 1404
4 Electron Framework 0x1178e4158 v8::V8::Initialize(int) + 28
5 Electron Framework 0x11ad2caa8 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 39852376
6 Electron Framework 0x11ad2a594 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 39842884
7 Electron Framework 0x11698cb44 v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>) + 10256
8 Electron Framework 0x11698c89c v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>) + 9576
9 Electron Framework 0x1169730bc v8::internal::compiler::SLVerifierHintParametersOf(v8::internal::compiler::Operator const*) + 68188
10 Electron Framework 0x118ae2388 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 3895864
11 Electron Framework 0x118ae5a64 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 3909908
12 Electron Framework 0x118ae1cf4 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 3894180
13 Electron Framework 0x116b7ead4 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 13756
14 Electron Framework 0x116b7f9a8 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 17552
15 Electron Framework 0x116b7f7f8 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 17120
16 Electron Framework 0x116b7e3c0 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 11944
17 Electron Framework 0x116b7e4d0 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 12216
18 Electron Framework 0x1168883cc ElectronMain + 128
19 dyld 0x1a203ff28 start + 2236
```

My entitlements file contains this:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.personal-information.location</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
<true/>
```

---

Not sure if it's related but before I ran through the notarizing process once, I was able to sign the app and run it fine.

```
"electron": "^27.1.3",
"electron-builder": "^24.9.1",
"node": v18.16.1
```

---

Update: removing com.apple.security.app-sandbox lets me package and run the app

Comment: It depends on what profile and certificate you are using. Remember that if you try to open the application with the distribution certificate, it will not open

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide#get-certificates